# WSO2 ESB Pass Through Proxy Creation Source Code?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am looking for the source code of wso2 ESB, in perticular the source code of Pass through Proxy Creation but i am not able to find out. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check those here : [1](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v5/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/core/axis2/) , [2](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v5/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/config/xml/ProxyServiceFactory.java) and [3](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v5/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/config/xml/ProxyServiceSerializer.java)

Comment: Thanks Ratha for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Wso2 has published the detailed explanation for the architecture behind the passsthorugh in their library. Please find these link to access those.

demystifying wso2 esb pass-through transport [part-i](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/demystifying-wso2-esb-pass-through-transport-part-i/) , [part ii](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/demystifying-wso2-esb-pass-thru-transport-part-ii/), [part iii](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/04/demystifying-wso2-esb-pass-through-transport-part-iii/)